# Delete node and relationships using cypher query over REST API

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm playing with 2.0 M6 neo4j server (oracle jdk7 on win7 64).

I'm trying to delete a node and its relationships using a single cypher query over the REST API.

The query I create (which works if I run it in the browser UI) looks like:

```
START n = node( 1916 ) MATCH n-[r]-() DELETE n, r
```

Which by the time I put it through gson comes out as:

```
{"query":"START n \u003d node( 1916 ) MATCH n-[r]-() DELETE n, r"}
```

Which when sent to the server gets the response:

```
{
  "columns" : [ ],
  "data" : [ ]
}
```

My test fails because the node can still be found in neo4j server by its id...

If I simplify my query to just delete a node (that has no relationships) so its:

```
START n = node( 1920 )  DELETE n
```

Which becomes

```
{"query":"START n \u003d node( 1920 )  DELETE n"}
```

Then the node is deleted.

Have I missed something?

Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MATCH n-[r]-()` will only match the node if there is at least one relationship attached to it.

You want to make the [relationship match optional](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-match.html#match-optional-typed-and-named-relationship): `MATCH n-[r?]-()`

Also, you need to delete the relationships before the node.

So, your full query is:

```
START n=node(1916)
MATCH n-[r?]-()
DELETE r, n
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense and having made the changes you suggest it works perfectly :) Thank you.

Comment: This is valide in Neo4j 1.x version. Neo4j 2 introduced a new syntax: `OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-()`. Refer to Leland Cope answer.

Answer (score 15):

For neo4j 2.0 you would do

```
START n=node(1916)
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-()
DELETE r, n;
```

Answer (score 8):

Both `START` and the `[r?]` syntax are being phased out. It's also usually not advised to directly use internal ids. Try something like:

`match (n{some_field:"some_val"})
optional match (n)-[r]-()
delete n,r`

(see http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.1/)

Comment: so to delete all nodes (including disconnected ones) and their relationships you do MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r (nice that it works in a single line too)

Answer (score 4):

The question mark(?) is not supported in Neo4J 2.0.3, so the answer would be to use `OPTIONAL MATCH`

`START n=node(nodeid)
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-()
DELETE r, n;`

Answer (score 4):

And again there is a pretty syntax change. Neo4j 2.3 introduces the following:

```
MATCH (n {id: 1916})
DETACH DELETE n
```

Detach automatically deletes all in- and outgoing relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon latest documents and I have also tested it

```
START n=node(1578)
MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r
```

We have to put () around n and there is also no need of ? in [r?].

Even it works without `OPTIONAL`.